# How to access a file correctly in Java?

Tags: java, filereader

I am trying to get Java to access a file on my computer.

Could anyone help? What's wrong with the following code?
"Copy path" copied without the C: but I saw various examples where the name of the hard disk was indicated as such and it didn't work without the C: either...

```
public class GeneradorFrases {

public String leeDoc() {
    FileReader doc = null;
    try {
        doc = new FileReader("C:/Users/apple/Desktop/FRASES_FOR_HANGMAN.txt");
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("No se encuentra el fichero");
    }
    
    
    String linea = "";
    BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(doc);
    while (linea != null) {
        try {
            linea = buff.readLine();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("No hay frase");
        }
    }
    
    return linea;
    
    
    
    
}


}
```

I have watched various videos, taken notes, somehow I am stuck here.

Debugging tells me the variable "doc" is null, I get the NullPointerException.

Comment: Do not use `try-catch` to just catch the exception and do nothing. And specially don't continue you code like you didn't catch an exception, that doesn't make sense. At least look inside the error message of the exception to see what the problem is.

Comment: What operating system are you on? And, are you sure the file really exists in that path? The NPE is because you're getting a FileNotFoundException, but your `catch` block doesn't return early from the method or rethrow the exception; it just proceeds, even though the `new FileReader` failed.

Comment: @Progman thank you for answering. So the try-catch blocks should be in different methods?

Answer (score 0):

The code works just fine on my machine. The only way it failed (and got the nullpointerexception that you also get) is when the file doesnt exist. Make sure that the file exists in the location specified.(And early return/handle when catching the error so that the rest of the function doesnt continue while doc is still null)

Answer (score 0):

If *doc* is *null* then the *FileNotFoundException* is being thrown.

You should use a *[File](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html)* object, and check if the file exists using *[File#exists](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/20/docs/api/java.base/java/io/File.html#exists())*.
And, rather than continuing, just exit the method using *return*.

I'm unsure of your requirements, so I attempted to adapt your code.

You can use a *[try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html)* statement, which will automatically close the *BufferedReader*, which will close *FileReader*, also.
Not doing so can sometimes create I/O issues.

Additionally, typically when an *IOException* occurs during a *readLine* call, you'll want to exit the loop.
Although, again, I am unsure of your requirements, so I left it in.

```java
public String leeDoc() {
    File file = new File("C:/Users/apple/Desktop/FRASES_FOR_HANGMAN.txt");
    if (!file.exists()) {
        System.out.println("No se encuentra el fichero");
        return null;
    }
    String linea = "";
    try (BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
        while (linea != null) {
            try {
                linea = buff.readLine();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                System.out.println("No hay frase");
            }
        }
        return linea;
    } catch (IOException exception) {
        throw new RuntimeException(exception);
    }
}
```

If your file has multiple lines, you can review the following example.

```java
try (BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
    StringBuilder string = new StringBuilder();
    String linea;
    String newline = System.lineSeparator();
    int count = 0;
    while ((linea = buff.readLine()) != null) {
        if (count++ != 0) string.append(newline);
        string.append(linea);
    }
    return string.toString();
}
```

And, if your file only has one line you won't need the loop.

```java
try (BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file))) {
    return buff.readLine();
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Reilas... it has worked without the "C:" but I will make sure to look into incorporating your suggestions. I don't have requirements really, I am trying to build my portfolio by doing a Hangman with sentences :)